# ftp_connect() Workds from localhost but not webserver

Tags: php, ftp, synology

Ok so I have this code:

```
<?php
//user and pass
$ftp_username = "user";
$ftp_userpass = "pass";

// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "server_addr";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to {$ftp_server} from {$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

// then do something...
echo $login;


// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

I know this works, and returns 1 to the page when I load the page from my local computer. But when I run the page on webserver I get

Could not connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx from mysite.co.uk

The FTP server is a Synology NAS DS220j. I'm guessing the websites i.p address has been blocked by the NAS but I cant see the i.p address in my blocked list.

Anyone had this issue before and found a solution?

I've tried adding both the domain and I.P address to the NAS' allow list with no help.

Comment: It seems that your web server does not have connectivity to your FTP server. Did you verify that anyhow? This does not look like a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

I was dealing with the same issue a couple of months ago and it was due to different protocol versions since target server was updated and my code stopped working. The solution was to use PHP SecLib https://phpseclib.com/ then it worked fine.

Comment: My site is hosted on siteground. How would I go about installing it?

Comment: That's the beauty of PHP SecLib, it doesn't need to be installed, you just copy the folder on the server and the include files in your code. That's it.

Comment: phpseclib is an SFTP library. The question is about FTP.